# Split method error in python

Tags: python

I am learning python right now, and as an exercise, I am trying to create a program that encodes or decodes a string according to a caesar shift cipher where the shift of the cipher can be input by a user. However, when I run it, i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercises.py", line 52, in <module>
    print e(input)
  File "exercises.py", line 10, in e
    slist = s.split()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

Can Anyone help me with this? Here is the code:

```
import time
import string

print "Welcome to the Caesar Shift Cipher Encoder/Decoder"
time.sleep(2)
ed = raw_input("Do you want to encode or decode (e/d)? \n")
alphabet = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',      'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')

def e(s):
    slist = s.split()

    key = {'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':'', 'd':'', 'e':'', 'f':'', 'g':'', 'h':'', 
    'i':'', 'j':'', 'k':'', 'l':'', 'm':'', 'n':'', 'o':'', 'p':'', 
    'q':'', 'r':'', 's':'', 't':'', 'u':'', 'v':'', 'w':'', 'x':'',
    'y':'', 'z':''}

    input1 = raw_input("Type what you want to encode \n")
    shift = int(raw_input("What is the shift of the cipher \n"))
    for x in key:
        if (alphabet.index(x) + shift) > 25:
            key[x] = alphabet[((alphabet.index(x)) + shift) - 26]
        else:
            key[x] = alphabet[((alphabet.index(x)) + shift)]

    for letter in slist:
        letter = key[letter]
    result = " ".join(slist)    
    return result

def d(s):
    slist = s.split()

    key = {'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':'', 'd':'', 'e':'', 'f':'', 'g':'', 'h':'', 
    'i':'', 'j':'', 'k':'', 'l':'', 'm':'', 'n':'', 'o':'', 'p':'', 
    'q':'', 'r':'', 's':'', 't':'', 'u':'', 'v':'', 'w':'', 'x':'',
    'y':'', 'z':''}

    input1 = raw_input("Type what you want to decode \n")
    shift = int(raw_input("What is the shift of the cipher \n"))
    for x in key:
        if (alphabet.index(x) - shift) > 25:
            key[x] = alphabet[((alphabet.index(x)) - shift) - 26]
        else:
            key[x] = alphabet[((alphabet.index(x)) - shift)]

    for letter in slist:
        letter = key[letter]
    result = " ".join(slist)    
    return result

if ed == "e":
    print e(input)
elif ed == "d":
    print d(input)
else:
    print "That is not an option. Please try again."
    ed = raw_input("Do you want to encode or decode (e/d)? \n")
```

Comment: `input` is not defined in the script you've posted, so `e(input)` (and then splitting on input) will likely not do what you want. I would add `print s, type(s)` to the top of your `e` function, it should provide helpful information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a string to apply .split

Cast the input to a string like such:

```
if ed == "e":
    print e(str(input))
elif ed == "d":
    print d(str(input))
```

Comment: also I changed the name of the variable input so it was not a built in

Comment: and defined the variable outside the functions

Answer (score 1):

You call your functions `e` or `d` with `input`, which is a built-in (and no string). Ask for a string before that and hand that string over to your functions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting an error is because you are passing `input` to your function. `input` is a built-in function in python. Since you did not re-define `input` the actual function is being passed to your functions `e` and `d`. You can't split a built-in function. You need too pass the functions a string.

It looks like you don't even need to pass anything to your functions though. Try moving the `split` to after your `input1` line and splitting `input1` instead of `s`. This would make more sense then what you are currently trying to do.

Another thing to look at is in your function `d`. `alphabet.index(x) - shift` will never be greater than `25` but it could be less than `0`. You probably will need to change this.

Comment: thanks! your advice about my function d was helpful.